# Used a random user_agent when using Geopy. What could be the consequences?

Tags: user-agent, geopy, nominatim

So, I realise this is a stupid question but hear me out. I wanted to find out the latitudes and longitudes from addresses in a dataframe.But when I ran the following cell, I got an error that asked me to specify 'user_agent'.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
```

As a joke, I ran the code with my nickname as the user_agent, and well, the code worked. What do you think happened? Also, what could be the consequences?

Answer (score 0):

You can try openstreetmap.org

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="openstreetmap.org")
```